# Exporting individual pdf's for each plot created from a single file in R (using lattice)

Tags: r, pdf, plot, export, lattice

So I have a fairly large dataset of GPS locations corresponding to different individuals at different times. It looks like a more complicated version of this...

```
ID________________Year________________Julian.date________________Distance

1_________________2003______________________15_____________________200

1_________________2004______________________20_____________________500

1_________________2005______________________24_____________________462

1_________________2006______________________28_____________________51

2_________________2002______________________12_____________________248

2_________________2003______________________15_____________________571

2_________________2004______________________16_____________________685

3_________________2003______________________20_____________________521

3_________________2004______________________25_____________________1251

3_________________2005______________________29_____________________225

3_________________2006______________________54_____________________144
```

What I am trying to do is separate the data out by year and individual. So each individual with have a boxplot of their Distances and the corresponding Julian date. I am able to create a massive pdf of all the plots (12X11) on one sheet using the lattice package (Separator is a column combining the ID and Year columns)..

```
> barchart(Julian.date~Distance|factor(Separator),data=data)
```

This isn't particularly helpful as I can't do much with such a massive pdf. So I tried restricting the number of plots per sheet to 1 using...

```
> barchart(Julian.date~Distance|factor(Separator),data=data,layout=c(1,1))
```

Which results in all the plots flying past me and none of them exporting to pdf. I have tried searching for a way to accomplish this, but so far no luck. If anyone knows a way of getting these to export as they fly past I would be extremely thankful.

So thanks in advance if anyone out there can help out. And if you need any more information, let me know, I tend not to use the terminology properly.

Ayden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing, or doing wrong as you don't show code, but using an example modified from `?barchart` I see a PDF with multiple pages using this code:

```
foo <- barchart(yield ~ variety | site, data = barley,
              groups = year, layout = c(1,1), stack = TRUE,
              auto.key = list(space = "right"),
              ylab = "Barley Yield (bushels/acre)",
              scales = list(x = list(rot = 45)))

pdf("foo.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
print(foo)
dev.off()
```

`onefile = TRUE` should be the default and allows multiple pages in a single PDF. The other thing I do is print the barchart object in the `pdf()` wrapper; again, I don't think this is required if you are running R interactively but it will be needed if this is a batch or script based job.

Comment: Ah perfect! The onefile=TRUE for printing was exactly what I needed. I ended up just using the coding in my OP but assigning it's results to a file. Then using the second part of your code, printed off that file with the onefile code line and it worked beautifully. Thanks so much!